# Adding Files in VS express

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file, project, loading

I have started using files like images in my projects and I've got a problem. If I needed to test any program that use image. I would do it from Debug folder, but I found it not that convenient. So could you help me and tell how can I add images or other files to project in order to run it right from VS and debug.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be "how to make sure my exe knows where files are when launched both from IDE and separately". Only way this can happen is if files are in the same directory as exe(or relative to it), since there's where your program will be searching when launched on its own. Now, to convince VS to put everything in the same folder you need to:

1. Create a folder, let's say it will be called WorkingDir and be located in your project directory
2. Put your sound files in there
3. In VS right click on project -> properties -> configuration properties -> general -> target name and set it to $(ProjectName)_$(Configuration)
4. set output directory(on the same page) to $(ProjectDir)WorkingDir
5. go to debugging and set working directory to $(ProjectDir)WorkingDir